# MySQL Select column name include variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to transfer data from a MySQL database, select the column related to the language of values from my goal.

MySQL table's name is `catalogs`
Mysql column names are  `id`, `name_en`, `name_de`, `name_ru`, `content_en`, `content_de`, `content_ru`, `image`

language short code comes from `_GET` request

For example, the URL looks like the following
`catalogs.php?id=1&lan=en`

My PHP Code Looks like the following

```
$get_id = $_GET['id'];
$lan = $_GET['lan'];

$sql = $mysqli -> query("SELECT id, name_$lan, content_$lan, image FROM catalogs WHERE id='$get_id'");
while($row = $sql->fetch_array()){
   echo $row['name'];
 //nothing display
}
```

Comment: Because your '$get_id' is not evaluated correctly, try id=$get_id whithout the quotes

Comment: That doesn't scale very well; instead you should use one `name` and one `content` column and use for example your language code or an integer in an additional column to set the language of the record.

Comment: Your code is dangerous and not secure. It is vulnerable to SQL injection, read up here and consider using PDO with bound parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Agreeing with last two comments. 1) Your schema is bad if you have to resort to variable field names. 2) This is a major SQL injection risk. Fixing number 1 (adding language as it's own field and having multiple records for each catalog id) will allow you to solve number 2 with parameterized mysqli/PDO logic. It might also fix the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Thank you @delboy1978uk abbreviated code and I'm just trying to understand the logic

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto my code is true no problem

Comment: `var_dump($row)` and tell us what it gives you